# Understanding object creation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

can some one plz explain why i have to declare formhandler like this ?

```
var FormHandler = App.FormHandler; //Like Java just putting a type to the variable.

var formHandler = new FormHandler(FORM_SELECTOR);
```

And why i cant just declare it like this.

```
var formHandler = new FormHandler(FORM_SELECTOR);
```

Why is the first line needed?

Here is the full FormHandler code in case it is needed to answer the question.

```
(function (window){
'use strict';
var App = window.App || {};
var $ = window.jQuery;

function FormHandler(selector) {
if(!selector) {
  throw new Error('No selector provided');
}

this.$formElement = $(selector);
if(this.$formElement.length === 0){
  throw new Error('Could not find element with selector: ' + selector);
 }
}

FormHandler.prototype.addSubmitHandler = function(fn) {
console.log('Setting submit handler for form');
this.$formElement.on('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();

  
  var data = {};
  $(this).serializeArray().forEach(function(item) {
    data[item.name] = item.value;
    console.log(item.name + ' is ' + item.value);
  });
     console.log(data);
     fn(data);
    });
  };

  App.FormHandler = FormHandler;
  window.App = App;
 })(window);
```

Comment: looks like you could just do `var formHandler = new App.FormHandler(FORM_SELECTOR);`

Answer (score 4):

`FormHandler` doesn't exist in the global context (which is `window` in this case) because it was never assigned to it.

`App` does exist in the global context due to the line `window.App = App`.

So in your script you can just toss out `App` and it will find it on `window.App` but if you toss out `FormHandler` without defining it then it won't find anything and will cause a reference error.

If you need to make a FormHandler you must reference `App.FormHandler`. But the way you've written it is extraneous, it can just be done like this:

```
var formHandler = new App.FormHandler(FORM_SELECTOR);
```